# What should I pass to the .success() for `Result<Void, Error>`?

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I have a network request, but I don't really care about the success response, so I use a `Result<Void, Error>` for return value. The problem is when I assign `.success()` to it, the compiler return the following error:

> Missing argument for parameter #1 in call

I have tried passing `empty`, `nil`, but neither can pass the compiling.

The code is like this:

```
var result: Result<Void, Error>?
result = .success()
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`result = .success(())` should work

Comment: Wow ! i thought i had enough braces :)

Comment: Saw another thread on this. I used .success(Void()) which is longer but doesn't seem to make it more obvious